# Xml - When deserializing set a variable like Foo.Fuu.X

Tags: c#, xml, xna, xml-serialization

The problem is that I have a Screen Manager in my "game" and when switching between screens, I use Xml to instantiate a screen and set some parameters to it, and the thing is that I have no idea how to assign values to properties that can not be just written to a xml file. Doesnt make sense? Better if you see code.

Example xml-code:

```
<GameScreen>
   <Timer>
      3 //no problem here
   </Timer>
   //but how do I do stuff like this?
   //Dimensions is a vector2 from XNA
   <FadeImage>
      <Scale>
          ScreenManager.Dimensions
      <Scale>    
   </FadeImage>
 <GameScreen>
```

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
<Foo>
   <FooVar>3</FooVar>
   <FooVarRow>
      <FooVarCol>11</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>12</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>13</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>14</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>15</FooVarCol>
   </FooVarRow>
   <FooVarRow>
      <FooVarCol>21</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>22</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>23</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>24</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>25</FooVarCol>
   </FooVarRow>
   <FooVarRow>
      <FooVarCol>31</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>32</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>33</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>34</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>35</FooVarCol>
   </FooVarRow>
   <FooVarRow>
      <FooVarCol>41</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>42</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>43</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>44</FooVarCol>
      <FooVarCol>45</FooVarCol>
   </FooVarRow>
</Foo>​
```

Comment: what is this and how it is supposed to help?

Comment: I assume this is what your xml file will look like. You need to add a two dimensional table to the XML that has rows and columns.

Comment: but what for? the problem is that I want dynamically load ScreenManager.Dimensions into Image.Scale instead of hardcoding into an xml file every time screen resolution changes